# Get Font used in .txt file before loadind to richTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get the font set in .txt file (or .rtf) before loading it to a richTextBox. If I don't do this the default font is set and the richTextBox.Text's font is different than the one set in the original .txt file...

I'm dealing with a custom TextPanel inherited from RichTextBox.

```
    if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".txt")
                {
                    // I need to get the font here from the path "file" .txt document
                    textPanel = new TextPanel(file, this);
                    textPanel.LoadFile(file, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, just can't find it :(

Comment: I'm not sure if you can store font data in a .txt file, I may be wrong but I think a .txt file is literally for storing text

Comment: Do you mean the font name is stored in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain text files don't store font information. (They're **plain** text files, meaning they only store text.) When they're loaded, they use the font of the container they're displayed in.

If an actual richtext (`.rtf`) file has font information, and it's loaded as an .rtf file (don't use `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText`, and use `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText` instead), the `RichTextBox` should automatically set the font for you with no code involved.

Comment: Good catch on the PlainText/RichText. +1

Answer (score 4):

Thomas, .txt doesn't store font information, unless you have a custom file format that you're not noting in the question.  Changing the text in, say, NotePad, is simply a display feature and doesn't do anything to the file itself.

RTF does store the font information and should be loaded when you push it to the RTB.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks for swift reply. I'm surprised this cannot be done... isn't there any information or meta information stored in the .txt file when it is saved ?

Comment: No, only in the RT files, and only if you load them as Ken has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

TXT files don't have a header. They are plain text files without any additional file structure or implicit format (like RTF). You can use, for example, default font style of your application when you open them... or default NotePad font (Lucida Console, normal, 10).